# CPS cap, Minecraft 1.8 pvp unplayable (ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: 22.04, mouse, minecraft, doubleclick

How do I remove Linux's CPS (clicks per second) cap? Btw, using Bloody A60 and A70. So with this CPS cap (10-12 CPS) when I click 40 CPS on Windows, on Ubuntu, it's 10 CPS. How do I fix it? I tried a large amount of terminal commands, if this doesn't get fix, I'll stick to Windows like my friend.